# why I have refused the connection of db

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, apache-commons-dbcp, jdbc-pool

I have web application. And I have jdbc database pooling system.

If my **minIdle** and **initialSize** value are 50, I have the following error:

```
[ WARN] [http-nio-8080-exec-25 03:11:33] (SqlExceptionHelper.java:logExceptions:144) SQL Error: 12519, SQLState: 66000
[ERROR] [http-nio-8080-exec-25 03:11:33] (SqlExceptionHelper.java:logExceptions:146) Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found
```

might be this is because I should configure XE oracle to get many connections.

I do something like this:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET processes=10000 scope=spfile
```

But this did not help me.

Also:

```
SQL> connect
Enter user-name: system
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> select count(*) from v$process;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        44

SQL> show parameter processes;

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- -----------------------
aq_tm_processes                      integer     0
db_writer_processes                  integer     1
gcs_server_processes                 integer     0
global_txn_processes                 integer     1
job_queue_processes                  integer     4
log_archive_max_processes            integer     4
processes                            integer     100
SQL>
```

I have windows 7 x64. and this is Oracle Express edition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get this Oracle connections error? ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795580/why-do-i-get-this-oracle-connections-error-ora-12519-tnsno-appropriate-servic)

Comment: Yes. this is only Oracle Db problem. I have another Oracle Server (not XE) and there everything works well.

Comment: What makes you think you may be low on processes? Can you edit your post to provide your listener.ora for the server? What version/OS of the DB are you running? Also run `select count(*) from v$process;` and `show parameter processes;`

Comment: I have just update my post. please see it. thanks!

Comment: How can I change job_queue_processes   process? and also processes?

Comment: also what does select count(*) from v$process means? could u tell me?..

Comment: after you do the alter session, set scope to spfile - you have to bounce the database to have the setting to take affect - also, i'm not convinced this is the actual cause of your ORA-12519

Answer (score 0):

If too many connection opened within a short time can cause this. You should check in your processes.
You may make system sleep for some time after some connection.