# Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

I work with `Spring` and `Hibernate` and I used `Oracle 11g` as database
and I used `JBoss 5`.

I have a problem to re-establish the connection automatically

I used `c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar`

This my config in my application :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>
         <bean id="dataSource" class = "com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
       <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>

        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:production"/> 



        <property name="user" value="admin"/>
        <property name="password" value="admin"/>
             <!-- pool sizing -->
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="1" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="1" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="200" />
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="3" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />

        <!-- retries -->
        <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="30" />
        <property name="acquireRetryDelay" value="1000" /> <!-- 1s -->
        <property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure" value="false" />

        <!-- refreshing connections -->
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="180" /> <!-- 3min -->
        <property name="maxConnectionAge" value="10" /> <!-- 1h -->

        <!-- timeouts and testing -->
        <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="30000" /> <!-- 30s -->
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="60" /> <!-- 60 -->
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true" /> 
        <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL" />
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true" /> 

    </bean>
</beans>
```

But I have this error :

```
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool] (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1) com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@1a88493f -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:263)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:389)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:454)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:802)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
2016-04-06 10:00:09,300 INFO  [STDOUT] (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0) 10:00:09,300 WARN  [BasicResourcePool:1841] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@696dbdb5 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:263)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:389)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:454)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:802)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
2016-04-06 10:00:11,925 WARN  [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool] (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2) com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@8003d4a -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:263)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:389)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:454)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:802)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
2016-04-06 10:00:11,956 WARN  [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool] (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0) com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@75354d7 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:263)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:389)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:454)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:802)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
2016-04-06 10:00:11,956 WARN  [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool] (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0) com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@7ddd60e7 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:263)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:389)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:454)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:802)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
2016-04-06 10:00:11,956 WARN  [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool] (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1) com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@2704e3a7 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:263)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:389)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:454)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:802)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
2016-04-06 10:00:11,972 WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (http-172.30.50.21-80-11) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
2016-04-06 10:00:11,972 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (http-172.30.50.21-80-11) An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
2016-04-06 10:00:11,972 WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (http-172.30.50.21-80-58) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
2016-04-06 10:00:11,972 WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (http-172.30.50.21-80-53) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
2016-04-06 10:00:11,972 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (http-172.30.50.21-80-53) Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
```

my application works correctly using the previous database configuration but my problem is that the error appeared when I have many connection to my application ( more than 200 users ) that why I used connection pool .

and when I have this error in the server  oracle service  works correctly since I can directly execute the query in the database.
juste the problem is  between the connection of my application which are deployed in jboss and oracle

in **_BaseRootDAO.java** I have this method :

```
/**
 * Return a new Session object that must be closed when the work has been completed.
 * @return the active Session
 */
public Session getSession() {
    return getSession(
        getConfigurationFileName());
}

/**
 * Return a new Session object that must be closed when the work has been completed.
 * @param configFile the config file must match the meta attribute "config-file" in the hibernate mapping file
 * @return the active Session
 */
protected Session getSession(String configFile) {
    if (null != session && session.isOpen()) return session;
    else if (null != sessionFactory) {
        Session s = currentSession.get();
        if (null == s || !s.isOpen()) {
            s = sessionFactory.openSession();
            currentSession.set(s);
        }
        return s;
    }
    else {
        Session s = currentSession.get();
        if (null == s || !s.isOpen()) {
            s = getSessionFactory(configFile).openSession();
            currentSession.set(s);
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

**update :**

this is the current settings in the Oracle database

```
RESOURCE_NAME, CURRENT_UTILIZATION, MAX_UTILIZATION

sessions    93  156
enqueue_locks   81  149
enqueue_resources   18  52
```

I try to use the last version of  c3p0

**c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar** insted of  **c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**My use case:**
I was running parallel connections to the DB(Oracle 12c) - 1 instance - to test if i get different sequence values from a sequence. As the parallel connections increase, there was a point where i got `"ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found"`

**What worked:**

1.The processes limit_value was being hit. I increased it.

```
 ALTER system SET processes=XXX SCOPE=SPFILE;
```

***Increase XXX incrementally(like +200 or so), because if you increase it to a too high value in 1 go, you might not be able to start your Oracle instance, as it cannot support it(READ: memory limitation, operating system limitation, ...)***

2. commit;
3. Restart DB.
   ***(IMPORTANT: Do not forget to restart the DB, to make the change effective in the `spfile`. For both static and dynamic parameters, changes are recorded in the `spfile`, and will only take effect in the next restart.)***
4. Verify my change(limit_value):

```
select resource_name, current_utilization, max_utilization, limit_value
from v$resource_limit
where resource_name = 'processes';

show parameters processes; // will also work
```

**NOTE:** You might notice that the `sessions` parameters will also change. This is because `sessions` and `processes` work hand-in-hand, and Oracle will re-compute the `sessions` limit_value based on the chosen `processes` limit_value.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's leave for later time the things with Oracle Listener/DB configurations and try the simple things:
Could you please check if the jdbc url is correct one? Please pay attenion on the SID and service name differences in this case:
For SID

```
<property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:production"/>
```

For Service Name

```
<property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/production"/>
```

Some useful links:
[Why do I get this Oracle connections error? ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795580/why-do-i-get-this-oracle-connections-error-ora-12519-tnsno-appropriate-servic) 
[Java JDBC - How to connect to Oracle using Service Name instead of SID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832056/java-jdbc-how-to-connect-to-oracle-using-service-name-instead-of-sid)

Comment: thank you for your response ,  my application works correctly using the previous database configuration
but my problem is that previous error appeared when I have many connection to my application ( more than 200 users )

that why I used connection pool

Comment: Now this makes sense. In this case there might be two things: either some issues in the Connection Pool config, or the number of connections is too big. For the second issue please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9561838/1453045

Answer (score 0):

You can try using "Universal Connection Pool" which is a Java connection Pool for your test.  Refer to the blog "[UCP with Hibernate](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/entry/how_to_use_oracle_universal)" for more details.